# How can I use timestamps in Absinthe? (Phoenix 1.3)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I have a problem with phoenix 1.3 + absinthe.

I try this code:

```
schema "urls" do
  field :path, :string

  timestamps()
 end

object :url do
  field :id, :id
  field :path, :string
  field :inserted_at, :datetime
end
```

It work with `id` and `path` but it fails with `inserted_at` with:

```
Inserted_at :datetime is not defined in your schema.          

Types must exist if referenced.   


lib/absinthe/schema.ex:230: Absinthe.Schema.__after_compile__/2     
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6                     
(elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`datetime` is not part of the [default scalar types](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types) that GraphQL comes with. [Here](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/custom-scalars.html#defining-a-scalar) you can find out how to build custom scalar types with Absinthe. Luckily [datetime scalar type](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe/blob/v1.3.2/lib/absinthe/type/custom.ex#L10) is already part of Absinthe and the only thing you need to do in order to use it is to import it:

```
import_types Absinthe.Type.Custom
```

Comment: How to do it for geo location?i mean geo co-ordinates (langitude and longitude) in GraphQl